# Unable to debug in PyDev eclipse. KeyError pydev_ipython.matplotlibtools

Tags: eclipse, ipython, pydev

In PyDev Eclipse Mars I get an error when I want to debug a script. In the debug console I get the error:

```
Error unable to add break on exception for: StandardError (exception could not be imported)
```

and additionally I get a Caught Exceptions tab which shows

```
<class 'KeyError'>:'pydev_ipython.matplotlibtools' - MainThred - pid_25386_id_140237683517184'.
```

Now I am absolutely clueless about what is the issue, but I noticed that the debugging problems only started after I pip installed the IPython console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same error in my Eclipse Neon with PyDev 5.1.2 install:

```
Error unable to add break on exception for: StandardError (exception could not be imported)
```

While the error seems harmless (debugging works OK here) it's still annoying so to get rid of it I selected Run -> Manage Python Exception Breakpoints and unchecked StandardError.

I also prefer to use the standard Python shell for debugging instead of IPython; you can achieve the same by editing

```
eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_VERSION_HERE/pysrc/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console.py
```

and uncommenting `"raise ImportError()"`